# How should I acknowledge a new baby under Islam in western society?

Tags: non-muslim, non-muslim-countries, baby, celebration

My parent's neighbors are Muslim. We are not. The neighbors' daughter in law just gave birth to their first grandchild, a little girl who is named Fatima.

In the US, one gives a gift for a new baby. Would it offend the family to do so?

I customarily give a small stuffed animal for the child. I have been told that figurative representations of living things is sinful under Islam. Does this apply to toys?  What kind of gift, if any, would be  appropriate?

If it makes a difference, the new mother  works, wears western clothes but  covers her head. The mother in law does not cover her head.

Thank you for  your information and guidance.

I am in the US. When you respond, please recall that I am not Muslim and do not know Arabic words.

Answer (score 6):

Islam does have some restrictions on imagery. Those are mostly in terms of depicting religious figures ( Muhammad, Jesus, Mary, Moses [pbuh] ). However some cultures apply those restrictions to personal lives too based on their interpretation of Islam.

The way you described your friends, they would not be offended by some one who doesn't know much about Islam. So relax, we are really a peace loving people.

Alternatively, you could change your gift to something simple like a crawl mat or Hanoi toy or onesies.

Even better... toysrus gift card.... as my grandpa always said "cash is king"

This is not an Islamic answer but I prefer to use hikmah ( i.e. intellect ) as the Qur'an requires us to.

Answer (score 4):

Giving gifts is a big part of Islamic cultures. I'm sure your neighbors will appreciate whatever thoughtful gift you choose to get them. Even things like playing with dolls are permissible for little children ([Hadith `Aisha](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/157)), and so your idea of stuffed animals would be completely appropriate.